# Function when Elements className change

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onchange, event-listener

I am trying to change the background image of a section based on whatever slide has a particular classname.

I have an unordered list that is genereated with a loop

```
<ul class="tes-image-links">
   <li>http://exampleimg1.jpg</li>
   <li>http://exampleimg2.jpg</li>
   <li>http://exampleimg3.jpg</li>
</ul>
```

I also have some javascript to change the background image of the section the unorderd list is contained in. The url for the background image depends on which div has the class name cycle-slide-active

```
var cycleSlide = $('.cycle-slideshow').find('.cycle-slide');
    for (i = 0; i < cycleSlide.length; i++) { 

        if (cycleSlide.eq(i).hasClass('cycle-slide-active')){
            var apimglink = $('.tes-image-links').children('li').eq(i).text();
            apimglink = apimglink.replace("http://localhost", "");
            $('.ap-testimonial').css('background-image', 'url(' + apimglink + ')');
            console.log(apimglink);

        } //End If

    }; //End For
```

The above code gives me the right background image for whatever slide is first loaded, but after the slide changes nothing else happens.

I need help Executing the above code whenever cycleSlide.className for any cycleSlide element is changed.

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: use `setInterval()` to set the time interval to check the class name is change or not

Comment: Are you using the [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/) plugin? Because if so you should be able to register for a `cycle-update-view` event using jQuery's `on` function.

Comment: Thank you Tamil Selvan and James Hay. Both Solutions worked. I ended up using James Hay suggestion. I did not know I was using the cycle2 plugin. I installed a wordpress plugin and didn't realize that's what they were using lol, definitely would have saved me a lot of time if I had known earlier.  Anyway thank you James for pointing that out to me, works perfectly.